# How can I clone a CodenameOne IntelliJ project and continue working on it?

Tags: intellij-idea, codenameone

I'm using a .gitignore file that was recommended for use with CodenameOne projects (See the [blog post](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-using-git-for-codename-one-projects.html)) and have committed my project to GitHub.  Now I want to retrieve that project to a new PC and continue working on it but I'm having endless troubles doing it.

Shai shared a ["quick trick" workaround](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-setup-codename-one-demo-from-git.html) which involves creating a new project then copying the relevant files from a clone of the Git into it, but then it's not a proper clone of the github repo that can be worked on and then synced back up to the remote.

So what I'm asking is: **what steps (and troubleshooting resouces) would I use to ensure that**:

1. I am storing the right files to the GitHub Repo to enable success
2. The IntelliJ Project will work with the retrieved files
3. I can commit changes back to the Repo going forwards.

Sorry, I'm a bit new to juggling GitHub repos and CN1's plugin structure for Idea has me mystified (I tried merging a new project with a directory which has a clone of the GitHub repo and the CN1 plugin is disabled - can't click on it)

Answer (score 0):

I resorted to using the following `.gitignore` (using Codepoint One with IntelliJ IDEA):

```
# macOS
.DS_Store

# build artifacts
/build/
/dist/
/lib/impl/
/native/internal_tmp/
/out/

# idea
/.idea/**/workspace.xml
/.idea/**/tasks.xml
*.iws
```

With this setting, most of the IntelliJ configs are committed, as well as some binaries: `CodeNameOneBuildClient.jar`, `JavaSE.jar`, `lib/CLDC11.jar`, `lib/CodenameOne.jar`, `lib/CodenameOne_SRC.zip`.

This is not optimal (the binaries don't really belong in Git and take about 40 MB combined). But this way I can clone the project on a different machine and start working right away. It also doesn't produce Git diffs on every build — but only if the libs are updated.

Answer (score -1):

IntelliJ/IDEA Codename One projects are nearly identical to NetBeans Codename One project with the one major difference being the additional idea directory. Just copy that directory from a working intelliJ project and add it to the gitignore. The project should work.